# Persistent layout in Next.js with TypeScript and HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, higher-order-components

I want to add a persistent layout to certain pages of my Next.js application. I found [this article](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) explaining a couple ways on how someone could do this. It seems pretty straightforward, however I have encountered the following two problems when using the recommended way of doing it:

1. I am using TypeScript and am not sure how to type it. For example, I have the following, which is working, but I obviously don't like using `as any`:

```
const getLayout =
    (Component as any).getLayout ||
    ((page: NextPage) => <SiteLayout children={page} />);
```

2. I am using Apollo and so I am using a `withApollo` HOC (from [here](https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo)) for certain pages. Using this causes `Component.getLayout` to always be `undefined`. I don't have a good enough understanding of what is going on to know why this is happening (I can guess), so it's difficult to solve this by myself.

---

#### Since asking this question they have added a [good example to their documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript)

Comment: Did you ever find a better way to do this than using `as any`?

Comment: I did not @knite

Comment: for typescript next js team solve the problem you can read this article for more info https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have the similar problem and this is how I solved it for my project.

Create a `types/page.d.ts` type definition:

```typescript
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { ComponentType, ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react'

export type Page<P = {}> = NextPage<P> & {
  // You can disable whichever you don't need
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
  layout?: ComponentType
}
```

In your `_app.tsx` file,

```typescript
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import type { Page } from '../types/page'

// this should give a better typing
type Props = AppProps & {
  Component: Page
}
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: Props) => {
  // adjust accordingly if you disabled a layout rendering option
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? (page => page)
  const Layout = Component.layout ?? Fragment

  return (
    <Layout>
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </Layout>
  )

  // or swap the layout rendering priority
  // return getLayout(<Layout><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout>)
}

export default MyApp
```

The above is just a sample implementation best suited for my use-case, you can switch the type in `types/page.d.ts` to fit your needs.

Comment: This works for me like a charm! You sir, saved my plant based bacon, and I'll be eternally grateful for that!

Answer (score 6):

You can extend Next type definitions by adding `getLayout` property to `AppProps.Component`.

`next.d.ts` (as of Next 11.1.0):

```
import type { CompletePrivateRouteInfo } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/router/router';
import type { Router } from 'next/dist/client/router';

declare module 'next/app' {
  export declare type AppProps = Pick<CompletePrivateRouteInfo, 'Component' | 'err'> & {
    router: Router;
  } & Record<string, any> & {
    Component: {
      getLayout?: (page: JSX.Element) => JSX.Element;
    }
  }
}
```

`pages/_app.tsx`:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

const NextApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  // Typescript does not complain about unknown property
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
  // snip
}
```

If you want to have even more type-safety, you can define custom `NextPageWithLayout` type which will assert that your component has `getLayout` property set.

`next.d.ts` (as of Next 11.1.0):

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { NextComponentType } from 'next/dist/next-server/lib/utils';

declare module 'next' {
  export declare type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
    getLayout: (component: NextComponentType) => JSX.Element;
  };
}
```

`pages/example-page/index.tsx`:

```
import type { NextPageWithLayout } from 'next';

const ExamplePage: NextPageWithLayout<ExamplePageProps> = () => {
  // snip
}

// If you won't define `getLayout` property on this component, TypeScript will complain
ExamplePage.getLayout = (page) => {
  // snip
}
```

Note that while extending Next type definitions you have to provide exact type/interface signature (together with matching generics), otherwise [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) won't work. This unfortunately means adjusting type definitions if library changes API.

Comment: In Next 12.1.6, `NextComponentType` is located on this path:
`next/dist/shared/lib/utils`

Comment: @tymzap `<P = {}...` gives a type error. Should it be `<P = object | undefined...` instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe next.js provides a `Component` prop as a part of AppProps. [This example](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#custom-app) should have what you are looking for.
2. You may need to assign `getLayout` after creating the component wrapped with `withApollo`:

```
import CustomLayout = CustomLayout;
const MyPage = () => (...);

const MyPageWithApollo = withApollo(MyPage);
MyPageWithApollo.Layout = CustomLayout;
export default MyPageWithApollo;
```

Additionally, next.js has two examples you can use to achieve exactly this (not written in typescript though):

1. [Dynamic App Layout](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-dynamic-app-layout/pages/index.js)
2. [With Apollo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo)

Comment: 1. I know it does, but `Component` itself does not have a `getLayout` function, so you need to change its type to make it work with TypeScript. Your example unfortunately does not help in the slightest.
2. Same problem since it's TypeScript, you can't just do `MyPageWithApollo.Layout` since `Layout` does not exist on the type `NextPage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if no Layout is defined in page, use this
const Default: FC = ({children}) => <>{children}</>

function MyApp({Component, pageProps}: AppProps & {Component: {Layout: FC}}) {
  // this will make layput flexible. 
  // Layout is extracted from the page
  const Layout = Component.Layout ?? Default
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

Let's say you want to use the  `Layout` in "Home",

```
import { Layout } from "@components"

export default function Home({
     ...
}
Home.Layout = Layout
```

Comment: I've already accepted an answer and it is now [part of their documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript), so this answer is not really providing anything useful

Answer (score 0):

Just do that! No panic, life is easy.

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
    
export default function Layout({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    return <main>{children}</main>
}
```